# Python Social Auth - How to know if social media connect is successful?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I have installed Python Social Auth. I use it to associate user site account with his social media accounts.

Facebook connect link is:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Connect</a>
```

Redirection works but **how to know if social media association is successful?**

If an exception is catch, I can display `get_messages()` function. It's perfect!
But any return if it's successful.

I have tried to custom a pipeline but I have not access to `request` variable to set message like it: `messages.success(request, "Successful message!')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have access to `request` in your custom pipeline:

> The pipeline functions will get quite a lot of arguments, ranging from the backend in use, different model instances, server requests and provider responses.

You can read more about it [here](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/pipeline.html#extending-the-pipeline).

and you can get access to `request` object like this:

```
def custom_pipeline(strategy, *args, *kwargs):
    request = strategy.request
```

and do whatever you wanted with `messages`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/error/'
```

in python social auth settings which redirects to the url you mention in above setting.
This way you will know whether the connect is success or not.
Hope this is helpful.